# Spring Data Neo4j 5: @Version field unexpectedly incremented when parent node is updated

Tags: kotlin, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Spring Data Neo4j (5.1.8.RELEASE).

Let's say I have a simple node that contain a simple relationship.

If I create a simple entity1 with a relationship to an entity2, and then update entity1 only, I would expect that only the entity1 version field is incremented. Surprinsingly, it seems that the relationship version also gets incremented. Is this behavior by design, or is this a bug?

```
@NodeEntity
class TestEntity(

    var content: String,

    @Relationship(direction = OUTGOING)
    var relationships: MutableList<TestRelationship>? = null

 ) : AbstractEntity() {

     fun addRelationship(testEntity: TestEntity) {
        if (relationships == null) {
            relationships = mutableListOf(TestRelationship(this, testEntity))
        } else {
            relationships?.add(TestRelationship(this, testEntity))
        }
    }

 }


@RelationshipEntity
class TestRelationship(

    @StartNode
    var startNode: TestEntity,

    @EndNode
    var endNode: TestEntity

) : AbstractEntity()


abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidStrategy::class)
    var id: String? = null

    @Version
    var version: Long? = null

    @LastModifiedBy
    var updatedBy: String? = null

    @LastModifiedDate
    var updatedTime: Instant? = null

}


@Test
@DisplayName("Test entity version")
fun testEntityVersion() {

    // Given
    val entity1 = TestEntity("Test1")
    val entity2 = TestEntity("Test2")
    entity1.addRelationship(entity2)
    repository.save(entity1)

    // When
    entity1.content = "Test1 (updated)"
    repository.save(entity1)

    // Then
    Assertions.assertThat(entity1.version).isEqualTo(1) // ok
    Assertions.assertThat(entity1.relationships!![0].version).isEqualTo(0) // fails!! expecting 0 but actual value is 1
    Assertions.assertThat(entity2.version).isEqualTo(0) // ok
}
```

Comment: Does it behave the same in plain Java? It might be kotlin interoperability issue.

Comment: The same thing happens in plain Java, so this is not a Kotlin issue. I just recreated the same setup in Java and got the same.